# exception_on_overflow parameter not working? PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I am trying to record some audio using pyaudio but whenever it goes through the recording loop a second time I get this error

```
OSError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981
```

I did some searching and found that in order to solve this problem you simply need to set the 'exception_on_overflow' parameter of pyAudio.read() to False. So I did that and then I get this error

```
TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exception_on_overflow'
```

this doesn't make any sense to me as to why it is 'unexpected' because in the PyAudio documentation it shows that it is a valid parameter for that function so is there anyone out there can tell me how to fix this problem? Thank you

Comment: In version 0.2.8 whilst `exception_on_overflow` is documented, it isn't acutally there. Check `help(pyaudio.Stream.read)` after importing pyaudio

Comment: Then what do I do to fix this problem

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733903/pyaudio-input-overflowed#28574532 and https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/51

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. So first I ran the command

```
sudo pip install pyaudio
```

Which installed version 0.2.11 of pyaudio. I looked in the code and I saw that it has the exception_on_overflow parameter in the read function. I tested it in my code and it worked! I hope this solves the problem for anyone else that has it